# Add NZGD2000 Coordinate Reference System

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geotools

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but...
I've been playing with GeoTools 8.0M-1, in particular trying to read some GeoTiffs. Each time, it crashes with the error **No code "EPSG:2193" from authority "EPSG" found for object of type "EngineeringCRS"**. The GeoTiff I'm reading is an NZGD2000 map. A Google for NZGD2000 and 2193 finds http://resources.esri.com/help/900/arcgisexplorer/sdk/html/612c4dad-84c2-7ec5-2e23-7db2bdfecc7d.htm ?

How can I get that information into the GeoTools, so that it will carry on and read the image via the GeoTiffReader class?

Thanks

Frank

Answer (score 1):

did you include a referencing jar in your project? See http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/geometry/geometrycrs.html for an example maven pom file (and other related code).

Comment: is right, dependency gt-epsg-hsql was missing in my case. Thanx!